# Displaying Images Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am using the following code to display images from drawable folder.
But now i want to display pictures dynamically.Every time a new image is added to the drawable folder i don't want go again in the code and add it in the array it should automatically increment and get displayed.
Any Idea how should I go about this.Just started working on Android.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.Handler;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private static ImageView imgView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);   

                                                                               final int[] images=images{R.drawable.ic_launcher,

    R.drawable.ic_launcher1,R.drawable.ic_launcher2,etc..};


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int i=0;
        public void run() {
            imgView.setImageResource(images[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>images.length-1)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,5000);  //for interval...
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //for initial delay..

 }
```

Comment: make images to static and whenever new image added add to images

Comment: make images to static and whenever new image added add to images

Comment: declare `public  int i=0;` as global

Comment: use **EventBus** and when new image added notify your adapter

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add the image Dynamically you can Naming the image File like this  : Image1.png; Image2.png; and so on.

And then you dont need to call all of them in the array, instead you can using lopp to get the name of the image in resource.

and then get the id using the code below :

```
public int getID(String resourceName,Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());
        return resourceId;
    }
```

Note :  after adding the image don't forget to increament the loop. hope it helps.

Comment: where will the change needed in the code.new to android

Comment: imageView.setImageResoure(). above method is returning the id of the image name.

Answer (score 0):

**please keep variable i as static**

i.e  static int i=0;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            imgView.setImageResource(images[i]);
            i++;
            if(i>images.length-1)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this,5000);  //for interval...
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //for initial delay..
```

Comment: add the static variable i under  private static ImageView imgView;  not in oncreate activity the declaration of static variable should be out of oncreate() method

Answer (score 0):

change the handle code as follow

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            imgView.setImageResource(images[i]);

            if(i>images.length-1)
            {
                i=0;
            }
            else
            {
                   i++;
             }
            handler.postDelayed(this,5000);  //for interval...
        }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //for initial delay..
```